# Comma placement: two prepositions in one sentence

Tags: punctuation

In the following sentence, should there be a comma in front of "pulsed?"

> Deposited thin films by means of, and prepared targets for pulsed laser deposition.

Comment: I can't imagine that sentence being parsed in any meaningful way unless another comma is added—or the existing comma is removed. (That would be a less common option.) As it is, it *sounds* like it should be two independent clauses separated by a single comma. However, what comes before the first comma is *not* an independent clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is not a sentence.

But this is a proper sentence:

The device deposited thin films by means of, and prepared targets for, pulsed laser deposition.

The second comma is not optional.